# nesting gnu parallels over many nodes

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I wish so run a loop, using gnu parallels that has the following form

```
outer loop about 5-10 iterations can be parallelized
    loop that cant be parallelized
        inner loop about 100s operations in parallel
        inner loop bit that can't be parallelized
```

due to the nature of unparallelizable loop there is no way of making this 1 parallel command.
I would like a minimum of one more of the outer loop to start to there is something to do whilst the inner loop is operating in it's single threaded bit.

I would like it so that not significantly more jobs than CPU cores are started, though this seems difficult to implement when nesting parallel commands.
Worse, if I specify a node file for the inner loop, it would seem that the nodes are going to be used in the same order every time the inner loop is run - leading to very poor scaling as the node count grows. There is the obvious method of use multiple node files that have the nodes in a different order.

Is a good way of controlling the number of simultaneous jobs is a nest like this ? the use of a named semaphore seems a possibility, passing a different node file each time run seems clumsy, or  am using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is simply to only parallelize the inner loop.

But `--load` may also work for you:

```
inner() {
   # Do inner stuff
}
export -f inner

outer() {
    parallel --load 100% -S .. --env inner inner ::: {1..100}
}
export -f outer

parallel outer ::: {5..10}
```